# How to get the user login duration from CloudWatch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

How I need to get the user login duration by writing query?

```
2020-04-24T17:41:21.216+05:30
END RequestId: 8caf16f6-b1ef-434b-a318-c8e3e545a737
10
2020-04-24T17:41:21.216+05:30
REPORT RequestId: 8caf16f6-b1ef-434b-a318-c8e3e545a737 Duration: 368.89 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 448 MB Max Memory Used: 121 MB Init Duration: 1037.35 ms
11
2020-04-24T17:41:21.215+05:30
Login successfull
12
2020-04-24T17:41:21.215+05:30
((1, 'Admin', 'krish', 'kittu', '6,7,8,9', 1, 'PRA0001))'),)
13
2020-04-24T17:41:20.846+05:30
START RequestId: 8caf16f6-b1ef-434b-a318-c8e3e545a737 Version: $LATEST
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455653/how-to-parse-the-message-in-aws-insight